# Need some help figuring out this error between Google Sheets API and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I've been writing a discord bot for a while now and Im moving some stuff to google sheets (which would allow other users to submit things through a link and automatically be put onto the google sheet)

So i'm using the code below to simply give me the information of the spread sheet, but I keep getting "GoogleSpreadSheet is not a constructor" upon following the NPM package info I updated google-spreadsheet but I still get said error. Im not sure if im updating it right or there is just something wrong with my code. Below is my examples

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

    async function accessSpreadsheet() {
        const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('my id');
        await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
        const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
        const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
        console.log(`Title: ${sheet.title}, Rows: ${sheet.rowCount}`);
    }


    if (msg.content == prefix + 'test') {
        accessSpreadsheet();

    }
```

and the error i keep getting

[image]

So I have it within my bot, that the moment I type *test, it should print the info to the console, but its giving me that error, I want to continue with this but if I can't even read the data then Im at a loss, some help would be amazing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I couldn't notice that you wanted to use the old version from your question. I deeply apologize for this. From your replying, I could understand that my answer, which uses the latest version, was not useful for your situation. So I have to remove my answer because I don't want to confuse other users.

Comment: No, I do want to use the latest version, however both your answer and my answer did not work in the latest version, I had to downgrade to make my answer work correctly. Im just worried because in September they're phasing out support for the older version, so it will no longer work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your comment, you said `I'll try that modification, for now it works`. So I thought that my proposed script worked for the latest version in your environment. Is my understanding correct?